# Как сделать modal через GET, как ВКонтакте?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, javascript, get

Как сделать modal через GET, как ВКонтакте? Например, `<a href="http://site.ru/index.php?id_photo_in_sql" id="modal">Открыть фото</a>`. Если я поставлю `http://site.ru/index.php?id_photo_in_sql` на браузер, то открывается modal. Как можно сделать?! Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ВК фото открывается в таком виде:

> https://vk.com/{USER_NAME/USER_ID}?z=photo{NUMBER}_{NUMBER}%2Fphotos{USER_ID}

Как можно увидеть

```
?z=PHOTO_ID

if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"?z=")) {
 //код
}
```

Может, я ошибаюсь, но как вариант...

Comment: @Ololoevv, Спасибо за внимание!